# Amazon Web Services Product Advertising API

Tags: e-commerce, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm thinking about making an affiliate site for the Amazon PAPI.  I'm wondering how the AssociateTag plays into the getting paid part.  If I have a link on my affiliate site, let's say:

http://www.amazon.com....&AssociateTag=XXX

Somebody clicks on that, gets sent to the page for that item, and buys it, then I g get paid?  Is it really that simple?  Can't seem to find this information.

The dev API talks about remote shopping carts but I'd like to avoid that if possible.  Thanks in advance,

Noah

Comment: @Adrian Petrescu I found this, by crazybob:  http://blog.crazybob.org/2008/10/how-to-create-simple-amazon-affiliate.html  Is that accurate?   Seems to easy. =)

Comment: Bob Lee is kind of a genius. If he says it works, I'd trust him :)